# Make a process sleep for a random time - Erlang

Tags: erlang

I would like to use the sleep function of the timer class and I would like to use it to make a process sleep for a random amount of time in between 0 and 1.

In order to do this, I tried:

```
timer:sleep(random:uniform()).
```

However, i get the following error message:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Apr-2014::21:39:32 ===
Error in process <0.472.0> with exit value: {timeout_value,[{timer,sleep,1,       
[{file,"timer.erl"},{line,152}]},{myModule,myFunction,4,[{file,"myModule.erl"},
{line,46}]}]}
```

What is wrong with this?

Also, as I have multiple versions of the same process, how can I make sure that each start with a different random number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{A1,A2,A3} = now(),
random:seed(A1, A2, A3),
```

You can run this code in every process start function. Because the randon seed is stored in process dictionary, every process has different process dictionary. you'd better set random seed for every process.

Then you case use `uniform() -> float()` to get an random number between `0.0` and `1.0`,
use `seconds(Seconds) -> MilliSeconds` to get the number of milliseconds in Seconds.
call `sleep(Time) -> ok` to suspend the process calling this function for Time amount of milliseconds.

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure what you mean for the second part of your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, no. My mistake, I was just being stupid! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Even when using `timer:seconds` I get the `"timeout_value"` error message.

It happens because `timer:sleep()` expects an integer value of milliseconds instead of a float.
Just add `round()` and it works:

```
timer:sleep(round(timer:seconds(random:uniform())))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide the right argument for the sleep function. According to the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#sleep-1) it needs the time in milliseconds. You are giving it the result of seed() which returns the *old state* of the random number generator. I suggest doing this:

```
random:seed().
timer:sleep(timer:seconds(random:uniform())).
```

*uniform()* returns number between 0 and 1 and *seconds()* converts seconds it to milliseconds

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was using uniform. I just mistypes. I tried your function in the shell and got 

** exception error: bad receive timeout value
     in function  timer:sleep/1 (timer.erl, line 152)

Thanks

Comment: @Harley, hi i had a typo there: it was timer.seconds, should be timer:seconds.